# What is the equivalent of OnRender in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm working on porting an app from WPF to Silverlight.

The app uses custom types derived from `FrameworkElement` (in WPF) to describe shapes, and text to be rendered on a `Canvas`.

The WPF app root node overrides `OnRender()` to iterate through a collection of 'child' nodes, calling `Render` on each child node to build the Visual Tree.

Silverlight doesn't expose `OnRender`, but there are hints that the same effect can be achieved using `ControlTemplate`.

Is this the way to go, and are there any good examples of using this method available?  I've done some googling (binging?) and found nothing really conclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct replacement for OnRender, but if you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351483(v=VS.95).aspx, you'll see that [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=VS.95).aspx) and [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride(v=VS.95).aspx) give you control over the visual tree within your control.

Comment: Thanks @gabe. I found other links related to that, but didn't find that one.

Comment: such as http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/10/24/loaded-event-timing-in-silverlight.aspx

Comment: I found OnApplyTemplate from the above link which looks like what I want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

What Gabe said, but there is an event that occurs when Silverlight is finished "Rendering" called CompositionTarget.Rendering:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering(VS.95).aspx

It is the closest analog to "OnRenderFrameComplete"

I would still suggest using the Measure and Arrange overrides, since they are the "right" way to do it.